# How can I compare if a pair of dates is present in a HashSet

Tags: java

I am trying to compare if a pair of dates exists in a `HashSet`

so my code looks like this

```
Set<Pair<Date,Date>> datesSet = new HashSet<Pair<Date,Date>>();
for (Custom obj: List<Custom> objs) {
    Date startDate = obj.getStartDate();
    Date endDate = obj.getEndDate();
    Pair<Date, Date> curr = new Pair<Date,Date>(startDate, endDate);
    // I want to check if the set contains those dates by value
    if (datesSet.contains(curr) {
        // Do something with obj
    } else {
        dateSet.put(curr);
    }
}
```

Will this work? How can I do it better

Comment: Have you ran it? Does it work?

Comment: What is the `Pair`? In Java Standard Library there's no such a class. Do you mean JavaFX `Pair`? Or maybe TestNG?

Comment: yes its Pair in javafx.util

Comment: It will only work if `javafx.util.Pair` properly implements `hashCode` and `equals`, which it seems to do. As @JeroenVannevel said... have you ran it ?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel its part of something really big... so lot of moving parts before I get to this.. so wanted to take an opinion before I get to this

Comment: @AbhishekIyer: you've managed to isolate your question; create a unit test to test it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work since: `javafx.util.Pair` has method:

> public boolean equals(java.lang.Object o) Test this Pair for equality
>   with another Object.
>
> If the Object to be tested is not a Pair or is null, then this method
>   returns false.
>
> Two Pairs are considered equal if and only if both the names and
>   values are equal.

`util.Date` has implmented equals too.

Of course it won't work for you if in your project you have other logic/definition of equals.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should work, since `javafx.util.Pair` [properly implements both `equals` and `hashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/util/Pair.html#hashCode%28%29).